# Display a JSON object made in java in jsp using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Hello i am trying to make a Json object in java and want to display the same json object in Jsp using javascript. Basically, i want to add 2 more options in my select box using ajax. Ajax is getting called and in the response i cans see the following o/p but not able to add the vales in the dropdown. Please help...
Want to do with JAVASCRIPT only.

```
{"value1":"label1","value2":"label2"}
```

Java Code:

```
Map<String, String> options = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
options.put("value1", "label1");
options.put("value2", "label2");

String json = new Gson().toJson(options);
//  json = "DataObject: [" +json+ "]";
System.out.println(json);

response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setHeader( "Pragma", "no-cache" );
response.setHeader( "Cache-Control", "no-cache" );
response.setDateHeader( "Expires", 0 );
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

Javascript :

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var responseJson=xmlhttp.responseText;
        alert(responseJson);
        var carobj = eval ("(" + responseJson + ")");
        select = document.getElementById("selector");
        for (var i = 0; i < carobj.DataObject.length; i++) {
            var d = carobj.DataObject[i];
            select.appendChild(new Option(d.value1, d.value2));
        }
    }
};
```

Jsp :

```
<select id="selector" onchange="showState(this.value)" >
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Use `JSON.parse()` to convert JSON, not `eval()`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `DataObject` in your JSON. It's an object, not an array, so you can't use `.length` or numeric indexes. Use `for (key in obj)` to iterate over the properties.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    var responseJson = xmlhttp.responseText;
    alert(responseJson);
    var carobj = JSON.parse(responseJson);
    select = document.getElementById("selector");
    for (var value in carobj) {
      select.appendChild(new Option(value, carobj[value]));
    }
  }
};
```